# Create a view/control so that in ios it is UIAccessibilityTrait.Adjustable using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uikit, accessibility

I'm developing an application for blind or visually impaired users. Right now in my application I have a value that can change from 0 to 10. I increase it with one button and decrease it with another.

When there is a value that can be increased or decreased, in iOS it is common to do it with a view that detects the swipe up / down gestures when VoiceOver is activated. These views you create are of type [UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitytraitadjustable). In Xamarin.iOS this value is part of the [UIAccessibilityTrait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiaccessibilitytrait?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) enumeration: UIAccessibilityTrait.Adjustable.

Is it possible to create a control so that in iOS it has this behavior in Xamarin.Forms? When compiling it for Android it should have the normal behavior with the increase and decrease buttons.

Comment: AFAIK, you'll need to do this via a [`custom renderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction) on iOS.